# Building OpenCV on Arch Linux can't find gcc

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, opencv

I have successfully build OpenCV using [this linux install tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) on an Ubuntu distribution in the past, but recently, I needed to build it on a Arch Linux distribution.

The command 
`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. -Wno-dev`  produces an apparently error free log including the following lines

```
Detected version of GNU GCC: 52 (502)
... <skipped lines> ...
C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
```

But when I run the `make` command, I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/gcc-5: No such file or directory 
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake:208 (message):   Error generating   /home/cecilia/opencv-3.0.0/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir
/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
```

This is clearly the wrong path. `gcc` is at `usr/bin/gcc`. To double check that `gcc` is on the system path, I ran `gcc -v` producing

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

Which matches the version number from the `cmake` log.

**Why does `cmake` detect the correct gcc version but `make` use the wrong path? And how can I resolve this error?**

---

p.s. The full cmake log is below in case I missed something that you can spot.

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 52 (502)
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /lib64/libIlmImf.so
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 8.2.1 [8.2.1]
-- at: /home/cecilia/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- CUDA detected: 7.5
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=compute_30
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.4" (found /usr/bin/python3.4)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.2" (found )
-- Found apache ant 1.9.6: /bin/ant
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- Found VTK ver. 6.3.0 (usefile: /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/UseVTK.cmake)
-- Assume that non-module dependency is available: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (for module opencv_core)
-- Assume that non-module dependency is available: /usr/lib64/libgl2ps.so (for module opencv_viz)
--   videoio: Removing WinRT API headers by default
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 4.2.5-1-ARCH x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.3.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.2.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /lib64/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /lib64/libtiff.so /lib64/libjasper.so /lib64/libjpeg.so /lib64/libImath.so /lib64/libIlmImf.so /lib64/libIex.so /lib64/libHalf.so /lib64/libIlmThread.so gtk-3 gdk-3 pangocairo-1.0 pango-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo-gobject cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 gthread-2.0 gstvideo-1.0 gstapp-1.0 gstbase-1.0 gstriff-1.0 gstpbutils-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 dc1394 v4l1 v4l2 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg avresample gphoto2 gphoto2_port exif /lib64/libbz2.so /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so /usr/lib64/libgl2ps.so /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so /usr/lib64/libpng.so /usr/lib64/libtiff.so /usr/lib64/libz.so vtkCommonColor vtkCommonComputationalGeometry vtkCommonCore vtkCommonDataModel vtkCommonExecutionModel vtkCommonMath vtkCommonMisc vtkCommonSystem vtkCommonTransforms vtkDICOMParser vtkFiltersCore vtkFiltersExtraction vtkFiltersGeneral vtkFiltersGeometry vtkFiltersModeling vtkFiltersSources vtkFiltersStatistics vtkFiltersTexture vtkIOCore vtkIOExport vtkIOGeometry vtkIOImage vtkIOPLY vtkImagingColor vtkImagingCore vtkImagingFourier vtkImagingHybrid vtkInteractionStyle vtkRenderingAnnotation vtkRenderingContext2D vtkRenderingContextOpenGL vtkRenderingCore vtkRenderingFreeType vtkRenderingGL2PS vtkRenderingLOD vtkRenderingLabel vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkalglib vtkftgl vtkmetaio vtksys dl m pthread rt cudart nppc nppi npps cufft
--     3rdparty dependencies:       ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 hal cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video viz cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo java stitching superres videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 python2 python3
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.18.2)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.46.1)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.3.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /lib64/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /lib64/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver ..)
--     TIFF:                        /lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /lib64/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /lib64/libImath.so /lib64/libIlmImf.so /lib64/libIex.so /lib64/libHalf.so /lib64/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.3)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 56.41.100)
--       format:                    YES (ver 56.36.100)
--       util:                      YES (ver 54.27.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       resample:                  YES (ver 2.1.0)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 1.6.1)
--       video:                     YES (ver 1.6.1)
--       app:                       YES (ver 1.6.1)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 1.6.1)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.6.1)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.6.3) / libv4l2 (ver 1.6.3)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     YES
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /home/cecilia/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use pthreads for parallel for:
--                                  YES
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 7.5)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
--     Use fast math:               NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/cecilia/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.10)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /bin/ant (ver 1.9.6)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.10)
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/cecilia/opencv-3.0.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/cecilia/opencv-3.0.0/build
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SO (but is too old to migrate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the opencv directory from my Ubuntu machine and assumed that `cmake` would overwrite any previously set variables. However, I believe the CMakeCache.txt was not overwritten, leading to the misidentified path.

Easy fix:

1. Download clean opencv distribution from http://opencv.org/
2. Follow tutorial as before.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should ‘‘accept’’ it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.  If this didn’t solve your problem, it shouldn’t be posted as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

First, your system isn't up to date. Update it with `pacman -Syu`. You said your gcc was version 5.2.0. The current version is 6.3.1. So somehow CMake wants to use `/usr/bin/gcc-5` which doesn't exist instead of `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Second, there's [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System). You can make sure your local ABS tree is up to date. Then copy `/var/abs/extra/opencv` to some directory and run `makepkg`.

Third, even if you don't want to use ABS for some reason, you shouldn't use `/usr/local` in Arch Linux. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_packaging_standards#Directories. You should use `/usr` instead.

Comment: Question is over a year old. I'm sure the poster has updated their system in the meantime.